# PHP using regular expression to parse query string

Tags: php, regex

How do I use preg_match to get a query string from a URL?

http://www.example.com/imgres?imgurl=http://www.example.com/images/blue-diamond-rings.jpg

How do I get 'imgurl' using `preg_matches` from the above URL?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PHP has functions for parsing URLs and query strings, you don't need to use a regular expression.

```
$parts = parse_url("http://www.mysite.com/imgres?imgurl=http://www.mysite.com/images/blue-diamond-rings.jpg");

$query_string = $parts['query'];

parse_str($query_string, $output);

echo $output['imgurl'];
```