# How do I extract query parameters from a URL string in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

Users can input URLs using a HTML form on my website, so they might enter something like this: http://www.example.com?test=123&random=abc, it can be anything. I need to extract the value of a certain query parameter, in this case 'test' (the value 123). Is there a way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular expression to parse query string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499538/regular-expression-to-parse-query-string)

Comment: Indeed, a duplicate, however the parse_url solution leads to a new problem, look at my comment to user576875 below.

Comment: you could extract the string starting from `?` with `strstr` or `explode` something and then pass that to `parse_str`

Comment: It looks like I can use strstr, thanks Gordon

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can use [`parse_url`](http://www.php.net/parse_url) and [`parse_str`](http://www.php.net/parse_str) like this:

```
$query = parse_url('http://www.example.com?test=123&random=abc', PHP_URL_QUERY);
parse_str($query, $params);
$test = $params['test'];
```

[`parse_url`](http://www.php.net/parse_url) allows to split an URL in different parts (scheme, host, path, query, etc); here we use it to get only the query (`test=123&random=abc`). Then we can parse the query with [`parse_str`](http://www.php.net/parse_str).

Comment: It seems like parse_url throws a PHP error when using certain URLs, check out this comment on php.net: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php#96433

Comment: Yes, it seems it doesn't work on URLs without a `host` component. This will work with valid HTTP-like URLs.

Comment: So, is there any other way to do this?

Comment: it don't need the host in URL, just question mark (?) and parameters, 

$query = parse_url('?test=123&random=abc', PHP_URL_QUERY);

Answer (score 2):

I needed to check an url that was relative for our system so I couldn't use parse_str. For anyone who needs it:

```
$urlParts = null;
preg_match_all("~[\?&]([^&]+)=([^&]+)~", $url, $urlParts);
```

Comment: just out of curiosity, but how come your system doesn't support a native PHP function?

Comment: @Vallentin - `parse_str()` was introduced in PHP 4... maybe (but it is much improbabile) he had a earlier version of PHP

Answer (score 1):

the hostname is optional but is required at least the question mark at the begin of parameter string:

```
$inputString = '?test=123&random=abc&usersList[]=1&usersList[]=2' ;

parse_str ( parse_url ( $inputString , PHP_URL_QUERY ) , $params );

print_r ( $params );
```