# What would be the most rational way to parse youtube video link for video ID in PHP?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Youtube API - Extract video ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6556559/youtube-api-extract-video-id)
>   [How do I extract query parameters from an URL string in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784243/how-do-i-extract-query-parameters-from-an-url-string-in-php)

If the input is as follows:

```
$input = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ALph_u2iee8&feature=topvideos_music';
```

And I want to end up with:

```
$result = 'ALph_u2iee8';
```

What would be the most rational way to do this in PHP?

Comment: I vote no duplicate: this questions always has the same format, the other has multiple formats and parses the links from a string.  This one is a much more concise question.

Comment: It is a duplicate. You (@Levi) should really post your answer in it. It's crazy to use a huge regular expression as the accepted answer suggests when PHP has easy to understand functions for the task.

Comment: I repeat my stance: this is NOT a duplicate. That question deals with any format of youtube url, and this one deals with one format.  Just because it is a subset question, it does not mean it deserves a subset or duplicate answer.  There is a very tailored answer to this format specified. The mechanics are not even close to the same.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**PHP has functions to deal with this already.**

```
$input = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ALph_u2iee8&feature=topvideos_music';

$queryString = parse_url($input, PHP_URL_QUERY);

$queries = array();

parse_str($queryString, $queries);

echo $queries['v'];
```

Comment: It's not really good practice to set variables in the local scope. I'd use the second parameter in that call to `parse_str()`. And of course, you could adjust the `parse_url()` and also check if the domain name matches.

Comment: @Matthew I changed it as I agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

Some will say to use a regex, but for something this simple, it is faster and better to go with subtrings.

This should do the job:

```
$input = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ALph_u2iee8&feature=topvideos_music';
$start = strpos($input, '?v=');
$length = strpos($input, '&', $start + 1) - $start;
echo substr($input, $start + 3, $length);
```

Of course, the parse_url/parse_str is the correct way.

Comment: My answer does indeed take 5 times longer to run than that of @Levi Morrison

Answer (score 0):

I use this function when I'm trying to grab a youtube video ID from a URL

```
function get_youtube_id_from_url( $url ) {
    preg_match('/[\\?&]v=([^&#]*)/si', $url, $matches );

    return !empty( $matches ) ? $matches[1] : false;
}
```