# php + regex - extract parameter data from a string

Tags: php, regex

I need to parse through a list of url strings and extract certain parameter values.

These strings are from a database NOT using POST or GET.

Here is an example url string and the goal is to extract the user_id part of the string.

```
https://www.example.com/?action=get_my_messages&user_id=9825&session_token=1463812ecbfa4
```

NOTE: the parameter order of the string might be different with different strings and in some cases the user_id might not even exist.

**FOUND SOLUTION**

```
$query = parse_url($request_string, PHP_URL_QUERY);
parse_str($query, $params);
$user_id= $params['user_id'];
```

**OBTAINED THE SOLUTION FROM THIS POST BELOW**

[How do I extract query parameters from a URL string in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784243/how-do-i-extract-query-parameters-from-a-url-string-in-php)

Comment: Everything here will be in the `$_GET` array. No need to parse or regex. For example `$_GET['user_id']` will have your value.

Comment: did you try something ?

Comment: [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) + [`parse_str`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)

Comment: That's overkill @iainn

Comment: @JayBlanchard It sounds like these URLs are coming from a file/etc, rather than just being the URL of the script. But maybe not.

Comment: I thought the example was pretty clear @iainn, but you could be right.

Comment: Yes, these strings are coming from a database, I just need to parse them and extract the user_id and then update another table in the database.

Comment: @chris85 - thanks! exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @chris85 I can reopen and someone else can dupe. It will not allow me to reclose.