# {PHP} Split text string

Tags: php, api, split

So I am probably making api system and I am trying to get the client req api.
I checked some tutorials and I found I could use :

```
$data = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
```

It's works but I am getting string like : `action=get&id=theapikeygoeshere`.
And I need to get only the text after `id=` , How can I do that?
Thanks!

Comment: use `parse_str()`

Comment: How about using: `$id = $_GET['id']`? http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I extract query parameters from a URL string in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784243/how-do-i-extract-query-parameters-from-a-url-string-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

parse the query string using [`parse_str`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php):

```
<?php

$arr = array();
parse_str('action=get&id=theapikeygoeshere', $arr);
print_r($arr);

?>
```

This gives:

```
Array
(
    [action] => get
    [id] => theapikeygoeshere
)
```

Comment: @Plugin4U you can then access individual parameters via the array, i.e., `$arr['id']` will give you the value of the parameter `id`

Comment: Why not simply use the `$_GET`-super global instead of parsing it yourself?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson sure, I thought that the question was about how to do it manually... :)

Comment: I think it's more about not knowing about how to read the query string params. I'm struggling to find any use case where you would need to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by using `$_GET['id']`. :) `$_GET` can be used for any URL parameters like those.

E.g.:

```
$info = $_GET['id']
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best thing is to use `$_GET['id']` but if you want to extract any thing from the **QUERY_STRING** use

```
parse_str($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"], $output);
var_dump($output["id"]);
```

Comment: _"but if you want to extract any thing from the QUERY_STRING"_... that's what `$_GET` does. That code basically just building your own `$_GET`-array, which doesn't make much sense.