# Adding Query string params to a Guzzle GET request without removing existing query params?

Tags: laravel, guzzle

I am using guzzle Http client request for GET method, what i am doing i am sending request to some dynamic url which i am fetching from DB and than appending some field into it and sending request
Example below :

```
$this->client->GET("https://webhook.site/bb1ea111-517e-46f5-867e-e956a75753f0?test=id&name=testname", 'query' => [
      'option_1' => string,
      'option_2' => string
   ]);
```

Now when i send request it goes like below

```
https://webhook.site/bb1ea111-517e-46f5-867e-e956a75753f0?option_1=string&option_2=string
```

So it removed default query params from url

Anyone here please let me know what i can update so that it should go like below

```
https://webhook.site/bb1ea111-517e-46f5-867e-e956a75753f0?test=id&name=testname&option_1=string&option_2=string
```

Comment: Just add them manually in the string without passing second parameter to the `GET()` method?

Comment: Are the URL query params always changing? If yes, https://stackoverflow.com/a/4784280/8119309 should answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **http_build_query** function and add it to your query string because Guzzle will replace array in **query** with the existing ones:

```
$this->client->GET("https://webhook.site/bb1ea111-517e-46f5-867e-e956a75753f0?test=id&name=testname&" . http_build_query([
    'option_1' => string,
    'option_2' => string
]));
```

Alternatively, you may extract parameters from existing url and send the complete params in Guzzle:

```
$url = "https://webhook.site/bb1ea111-517e-46f5-867e-e956a75753f0?test=id&name=testname";
$query = parse_url($url);
parse_str($query, $queryParams);
$params = array_merge($queryParams, [
    'option_1' => string,
    'option_2' => string
]);
$this->client->GET($url, $params);
```

I personally prefer second option because it is more clear.

Comment: yes i too like second option it worked well, the only issue i can see is while doing parse_str we need to do parse_str($query,$output) and than merge $output with other query string.

Comment: @MukeshRawat Oops! You right, i will edit the answer to correct that issue.